# unity transform.Translate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

Why it doesn't work? I need help)

```
if (transform.position != stopPos)
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I'm trying to move an object until a condition is met. As the condition is met, the object should stop moving.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform.position != stopPos
```

=> [`Vector3 ==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) uses an approximated precision of `1e-5`! What if your object overshoots the target? This is pretty likely to happen as `Time.deltaTime` for e.g. 60 frames per seconds is around `0.1666` which is way larger than this required precision for an exact match!

You would usually rather use e.g.

```
if (transform.localPosition.x >= stopPos) 
{ 
    transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime); 
}
```

or alternatively

```
var pos = transform.localPosition;
pos.x = Mathf.MoveTowards(pos.x, stopPos, Time.deltaTime);
transform.localPosition = pos;
```